# How do peer-to-peer networks and instant messaging applications connect directly to machines behind a gateway?

Tags: networking, peer-to-peer

If I am connected to my home wifi, it goes through my local router, and then my ISP, etc.

But with P2P software (e.g. bittorrent) and instant messaging applications, other machines can connect directly to my machine.

How is this possible?  I don't have a public IP address.

Comment: Any examples? Anyway, I think for those applications it may actually be your side connecting to the other side with public IP, not the other way around.

Comment: Bittorrent for example.  The other side is another user.

Comment: Try to seed only (ie run a torrent that's 100% downloaded) and see for yourself if other peers can actually connect to you. I'm sure no one will connect.

Answer (score 0):

You do have an public IP address. Everyone on the internet gets one from his
ISP when connecting via
[DHCP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_Host_Configuration_Protocol)
to the ISP's DHCP server.

This IP address is used to address your router. The router itself needs to be
configured with
[port-forwarding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Port_forwarding)
to your computer for the port(s) used by the P2P program.
Most often the P2P program creates its own port-forwarding using the
[UPNP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universal_Plug_and_Play)
protocol (if enabled in the router), and it then uses a random port
to which it connects dynamically.